# Php Obfuscator on Ubuntu 14

Tags: php

I am looking for PHP obfuscator without any server side plugin required. I would really appreciate any suggestions. Thanks

Comment: Do online obfuscator count? I recommend http://www.phpencode.org/

Answer (score 1):

You can try [YAK Pro - Php Obfuscator](https://github.com/pk-fr/yakpro-po)

Free, Open Source, Published under the MIT License.

I began testing some already existing php obfuscation tools, but I did'nt found one that was fitting all my needs.

I wanted a simple command line tool, based on a highly customisable config file, that would be able to:

- Be fast and re-obfuscates only files that were changed based on timestamps of files.
- Preserve some files and/or directories from obfuscation.
- Do not include in the obfuscated target, some files/directories that are present on the source project.
- Accepts lists of names and/or name prefixes to not obfuscate.

So I started to write this tool.

Comment: New: mini demo site:
[https://www.php-obfuscator.com/?demo](https://www.php-obfuscator.com/?demo)